# How to set the value of K.tile to -1 to match various inputs in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tile

I want to make a network like a photo.
[image]

Here, 200 would like to have the height and width of the network depend on the input (None).

This network is different from CNN.

The ConvCapsuleLayer is defined as follows.

```
class ConvCapsuleLayer(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, kernel_size, num_capsule, num_atoms, strides=1, padding='same', routings=3,
             kernel_initializer='he_normal', **kwargs):
    super(ConvCapsuleLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.kernel_size = kernel_size
    self.num_capsule = num_capsule
    self.num_atoms = num_atoms
    self.strides = strides
    self.padding = padding
    self.routings = routings
    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) == 5, "The input Tensor should have shape=[None, input_height, input_width," \
                                  " input_num_capsule, input_num_atoms]"
    self.input_height = input_shape[1]
    self.input_width = input_shape[2] #None
    self.input_num_capsule = input_shape[3]
    self.input_num_atoms = input_shape[4]

    # Transform matrix
    self.W = self.add_weight(shape=[self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size,
                             self.input_num_atoms, self.num_capsule * self.num_atoms],
                             initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                             name='W')

    self.b = self.add_weight(shape=[1, 1, self.num_capsule, self.num_atoms],
                             initializer=initializers.constant(0.1),
                             name='b')

    self.built = True

def call(self, input_tensor, training=None):

    input_transposed = tf.transpose(input_tensor, [3, 0, 1, 2, 4]) #[capsule_num, batch_num, input_height, input_width, atoms_num]
    input_shape = K.shape(input_transposed)
    input_tensor_reshaped = K.reshape(input_transposed, [
        input_shape[0] * input_shape[1], self.input_height, -1, self.input_num_atoms]) #[capsule_num*batch_num, input_height, input_width, atoms_num]
    input_tensor_reshaped.set_shape((None, self.input_height, None, self.input_num_atoms))

    conv = K.conv2d(input_tensor_reshaped, self.W, (self.strides, self.strides),
                    padding=self.padding, data_format='channels_last') #kernel_shape: shape of self.W

    votes_shape = K.shape(conv)
    _, conv_height, conv_width, _ = conv.get_shape()

    votes = K.reshape(conv, [input_shape[1], input_shape[0], votes_shape[1], votes_shape[2],
                             self.num_capsule, self.num_atoms]) #[input_batch_num, input_capsule_num, input_height, input_width, num_capsule, num_atoms]
    votes.set_shape((None, self.input_num_capsule, conv_height.value, conv_width,
                     self.num_capsule, self.num_atoms))

    logit_shape = K.stack([
        input_shape[1], input_shape[0], votes_shape[1], votes_shape[2], self.num_capsule])
    biases_replicated = K.tile(self.b, [conv_height.value, -1 , 1, 1]) #[input_height, input_width, num_capsule, num_atoms]

    activations = update_routing(
        votes=votes,
        biases=biases_replicated,
        logit_shape=logit_shape,
        num_dims=6,
        input_dim=self.input_num_capsule,
        output_dim=self.num_capsule,
        num_routing=self.routings)

    return activations

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    space = input_shape[1:-2]
    new_space = []
    for i in range(len(space)):
        new_dim = conv_output_length(
            space[i],
            self.kernel_size,
            padding=self.padding,
            stride=self.strides,
            dilation=1)
        new_space.append(new_dim)

    return (input_shape[0],) + tuple(new_space) + (self.num_capsule, self.num_atoms)

def get_config(self):
    config = {
        'kernel_size': self.kernel_size,
        'num_capsule': self.num_capsule,
        'num_atoms': self.num_atoms,
        'strides': self.strides,
        'padding': self.padding,
        'routings': self.routings,
        'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer)
    }
    base_config = super(ConvCapsuleLayer, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

There is error in `biases_replicated = K.tile(self.b, [conv_height.value, -1 , 1, 1]) #[input_height, input_width, num_capsule, num_atoms]`

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected multiples[1] >= 0, but got -1
 [[{{node conv_cap_4_3_1/Tile}} = Tile[T=DT_FLOAT, Tmultiples=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/conv_cap_4_3_1/Tile_grad/Sum"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv_cap_4_3_1/b/read, conv_cap_4_3_1/Tile/multiples)]]
 [[{{node metrics/acc/Mean/_375}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_8437_metrics/acc/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

However, if I change `-1` to `1` in `tile`, it is not what I want. The shape is `(200, 1 , 2, 16)`, but shape that I want is `(200, width_size, 2, 16)`. How can I do?

Comment: Doesn't it work with `biases_replicated = K.tile(self.b, [conv_height.value, conv_width.value, 1, 1])`?

Comment: @jdehesa I already did try that, but it doesn't work. The value of self.input_width is None, so some error occurs like it "Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [200, None, 1, 1]. Consider casting elements to a supported type."

The shape of input layer is (height, None, 1) and layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

Comment: Ah I see, right. The problem is that `conv_width` is not known at graph construction time, so you cannot use it straight away, but it's alright, you can use the dynamic value of the shape, which you already have in `votes_shape`, so I think this should work `biases_replicated = K.tile(self.b, [conv_height.value, votes_shape[2], 1, 1]`

Comment: @jdehesa So thank you! I have to check it a little bit, but it seems to work. I really appreciate for your comment :)